# gulp-less doesn't make CSS files anymore

Tags: build, npm, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-less

I'm using gulp for generating CSS from LESS. It has worked perfectly, but now the script seems to ignore the LESS files.

Here is my `gulpfile.js` (it is definitely correct, since I have not change it in the last time):

```
// Include Gulp plugins
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    filter = require('gulp-filter'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    path = require('path')
;
// Compile LESS to CSS
gulp.task('build-less', function() {
    const fileFilter = filter(['*', '!mixins.less', '!variables.less']);
    gulp.src('./public/less/*.less') // path to less file
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/')) // path to css directory
    ;
});
// Get vendors' code
gulp.task('build-vendors', function() {
    gulp.src(['./public/components/bootstrap/less/theme.less', './public/components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less']) // path to less file
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            //rename all files except 'bootstrap.css'
            if (path.basename + path.extname !== 'bootstrap.css') {
                path.basename = 'bootstrap-' + path.basename;
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css')) // path to css directory
    ;
});
// Run the build process
gulp.task('run', ['build-less', 'build-vendors']);
// Watch all LESS files, then run build-less
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/less/*.less', ['run'])
});
// Default will run the 'entry' task
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'run']);
```

And here is the call and the output:

```
$ gulp
[11:21:03] Using gulpfile /var/www/path/to/project/gulpfile.js
[11:21:03] Starting 'watch'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'watch' after 21 ms
[11:21:03] Starting 'build-less'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'build-less' after 13 ms
[11:21:03] Starting 'build-vendors'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'build-vendors' after 4.65 ms
[11:21:03] Starting 'run'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'run' after 5.37 μs
[11:21:03] Starting 'default'...
[11:21:03] Finished 'default' after 6.05 μs
```

The `whatch` also works correctly -- when I edit my LESS files I get an output like this:

```
[11:22:22] Starting 'build-less'...
[11:22:22] Finished 'build-less' after 1.96 ms
[11:22:22] Starting 'build-vendors'...
[11:22:22] Finished 'build-vendors' after 1.78 ms
[11:22:22] Starting 'run'...
[11:22:22] Finished 'run' after 5.08 μs
```

I also tried to run the `build-less` directly:

```
$ gulp build-less
[11:24:06] Using gulpfile /var/www/path/to/project/gulpfile.js
[11:24:06] Starting 'build-less'...
[11:24:06] Finished 'build-less' after 13 ms
```

No errors, but also no changes at the CSS files.

What might go wrong here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) uses [`multimatch`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multimatch) to match file paths against globbing patterns. The documentation for `multimatch` [has this to say about `*`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/multimatch#globbing-patterns):

> `*` matches any number of characters, but not `/`

Since you're trying to match files with paths like `public/less/foo.less` (which contain a `/`) using a single asterisk `*` doesn't work. You have to use two asterisks `**`:

```
gulp.task('build-less', function() {
  const fileFilter = filter(['**/*', '!**/mixins.less', '!**/variables.less']);
  gulp.src('./public/less/*.less') // path to less file
    .pipe(fileFilter)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/')); // path to css directory
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working again! But why did it work before? I've been actually using it several months with a wrong filter config and had absolutely no problems with it. Any idea?

Comment: A while ago there was [a backwards incompatible change](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-filter/commit/b0728ab9b667f04493fad10cc32d9135f1ead997) made to how `gulp-filter` matches file paths. I assume that's what's caused the issue.